# Can't connect to VNC server from outside network

Tags: vnc, vncserver

I am running a VNC server on Debian Jessie using x11vnc. It works fine on my home network, as I can connect to it from inside and outside the network. However, the system is going to be running on a different network. The VNC server does not want to run on that network properly. I can connect to it from inside the network, which is normal, but as soon as I go outside the network, it times out when trying to connect. I have a lot of experience with port forwarding and am positive I set it up properly on both networks.

What could be causing it to time out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, if you have set up everything properly then it must be a bug in the software. Or the hardware.

Comment: If it helps, I am using a belkin router

Answer (score 0):

At the VNC server side, from the router interface, you have to make port forwarding for VNC port (usually 5900). The interface or toolkit of each router may be different. You can enter `route -n` to learn the default gateway (which is the ip address that the router is defined in the LAN. Usually the router listens on port 80 for the interface, so you can just type the default gateway address to your browser).

Another solution may be to setup an openvpn server, add your computers as clients, enable client-to-client connection. This way, through tun0 interface, only through port 1194, the computers can see each other as if they are on the same LAN even if they are behind routers. You can use a minimal AWS EC2 instance with an elastic IP (static) for that. UDP port 1194 must be enabled in EC2 (not just iptables but from EC2 security settings).

Comment: I got port forwarding set up properly but it just times out when I try to connect. Any ideas?